# When I activate my custom plugin the menus and some styling of my site is messed up

Tags: plugin-development

I have created a custom plugin that I use to insert, update & delete data from database. Every thing is working perfectly but the problem is when I activate my plugin the menus in my site are disappearing and some styling is messed up,
How can I resolve this issue.
The plugin has it's own styles and JS files that are enqueued and are working properly.

thanks...

Comment: Have you tried turning on the `WP_Debug` or opening up the inspector and checking to see if you have any js errors showing? This can probably help narrow down this issue.

Comment: Yeah the console is pretty clear, nothing there, now I get know that I had enqueued bootstrap version 3, When I removed it it works perfectly.